# Apache ANT manifest classpath literal

Tags: java, ant, build, classpath, manifest

I have an ANT build that compiles my Java project and builds a jar. An ANT target creates a manifest classpath for the jar. Everything works great.

Now, I would like to add a period '.' to the beginning of the manifest classpath so that the runtime working directory is on the classpath.  How do I do that using `manifestclasspath`?

---

My manifestclasspath example:

```
    <manifestclasspath property="foobar.manifest.classpath" jarfile="whocares.jar">
      <classpath >

        <pathelement path="."/> 
          <!-- :-( adds the working directory of the build. -->

        <pathelement location="lib/some.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/someother.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${foobar.lib.dir}">
           <include name="**/*.jar" />
         </fileset>
      </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>
```

`<pathelement path="."/>`adds the **working directory** of the **build** to my manifest classpath which is not what I want.  I just want a period.

---

This is what I want the jar classpath to look like:

```
Class-Path: . lib/some.jar lib/someother.jar lib/blah.blah.blah.blah.b
lah.blah.jar /lib/and-on-and-on.jar
```

The key thing being the '`.`' as the first item in the classpath.

How to I make ANT add the literal '`.`' to the manifest class path?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by adding the literal "." ? Aren't the classes in the jar automatically accessible anyway ?

Comment: I'm loading override properties from a properties file in the runtime working directory.

Comment: Looking at the code, the path should always be relative to the jar you've specified. If "." is your project's `basedir` and "whocares.jar" is inside of "." then you should get "." inside the property or it is a bug (and you should report it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just prepend manually :

```
<property name="theRealManifestClasspath" value=". ${foobar.manifest.classpath}"/>
```